# How to shrink partition for lv snapshot?

Tags: lvm, snapshot

I want to try the snapshot functionality but I don't understand all the picture.
I'm on **Ubuntu server 11.10** and I've created two Volume Group and some Logical Volumes inside like this:

```
root@darwin:~# vgdisplay
      --- Volume group ---
      VG Name               data
      System ID
      Format                lvm2
      Metadata Areas        1
      Metadata Sequence No  2
      VG Access             read/write
      VG Status             resizable
      MAX LV                0
      Cur LV                1
      Open LV               1
      Max PV                0
      Cur PV                1
      Act PV                1
      VG Size               272.24 GiB
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              69694
      Alloc PE / Size       69694 / 272.24 GiB
      Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
      VG UUID               YRDCLM-ZfZN-kCoi-PIse-qMdn-2MBm-OmegqH

      --- Volume group ---
      VG Name               os
      System ID
      Format                lvm2
      Metadata Areas        1
      Metadata Sequence No  4
      VG Access             read/write
      VG Status             resizable
      MAX LV                0
      Cur LV                3
      Open LV               3
      Max PV                0
      Cur PV                1
      Act PV                1
      VG Size               67.75 GiB
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              17343
      Alloc PE / Size       17343 / 67.75 GiB
      Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
      VG UUID               ZRX1mD-CyhV-7u9f-15bh-2rnT-Nbee-1QD20u
root@darwin:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/data/var
  VG Name                data
  LV UUID                FuJlvb-NZ3H-YoaO-6Qsn-SYuz-QaHb-Ms2YtX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                272.24 GiB
  Current LE             69694
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/os/boot
  VG Name                os
  LV UUID                HE0izv-zuXu-0cZT-L3o2-O9Cj-5wEX-R4O6SB
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                188.00 MiB
  Current LE             47
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/os/swap
  VG Name                os
  LV UUID                4hlke0-kl3r-xVbN-Myjz-dH6H-hkRI-Uh7ncl
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                1.86 GiB
  Current LE             476
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/os/root
  VG Name                os
  LV UUID                7qpM1B-DjHp-v6Ju-Ia4L-TPtP-5sCF-UR6Mr3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                65.70 GiB
  Current LE             16820
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:3
```

and this is the df -h:

```
root@darwin:~# df -h
    Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/os-root    65G  1.1G   61G   2% /
    udev                  2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
    tmpfs                 792M  244K  792M   1% /run
    none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
    /dev/mapper/data-var  268G  528M  254G   1% /var
    /dev/mapper/os-boot   183M   51M  123M  30% /boot
```

At this point I don't understand if I need to shirink one LV making space for a new partition that will contains the snapshot, 'cause I tried to create a new LV but it says that there isn't enougth space. **Am I right?** If so, what is **the correct way to shrink?** For now, I want to create a snapshot of `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shrinking filesystems is possible but has its risks and is not recommended. It's going to be doubly difficult because the filesystem you'll likely need to shrink is `/var` - filesystems must be unmounted to shrink them (unlike growing, which is an online operation), so you'll need to boot from a recovery disc to do so. (It might be possible in single-user mode too.)

Procedure:

```
# Make sure /var is not mounted
umount /var
# Resize ext3 filesystem
resize2fs /dev/data/var <newsize>
# Resize LV
lvreduce -L <newsize> /dev/data/var
```

I'd also run an `fsck` of the volume once it's done to ensure there are no errors in the filesystem.

**Make sure** that you take into account that the LV size must be greater than the filesystem size - in your case at least 4MB larger as that's the physical extent size.

Have a read of the `resize2fs` and `lvreduce` man pages to understand the size specifications - in particular of `lvreduce -L`.

Comment: Ok I'll try with an ubuntu live cd. It's not a problem losing data, It's a fresh new install so if I lose something I can reformat and reinstall. Another thing that I don't understand, the LV for the snapshot must be the same (or greater) size of the used space in the partition I want to backup? Maybe a "future" dimension...?

Answer (score 2):

Linux Logical Volume Manager (LVM) is based on HP-UX LVM - which is in turn, based on Veritas VxVM.

One important difference between Linux LVM and HP-UX LVM is that a snapshot in Linux requires a preconfigured logical volume to act as the repository for snapshot data.

According to your `vgdisplay`, you've no space left on either volume:

```
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
```

You do need to reduce volumes. Most filesystems do not support shrinking - and those that do do not recommend the practice. Apparently, [XFS](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_Is_there_a_way_to_make_a_XFS_filesystem_larger_or_smaller.3F) and [JFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/9844/is-it-possible-to-shrink-an-jfs-filesystem) won't reduce (although XFS filesystems can be made larger). The filesystem ext2fs does support shrinking, but it's not a recommended practice: are you sure you won't lose some data?

Best practice is to do the following:

1. Backup the volume to shrink - use `rsync` or a `dump` variant.
2. Boot to a rescue disk - one that supports LVM.
3. Use `lvreduce` to reduce the size of the logical volume.
4. Use `mkfs` to create a fresh filesystem.
5. Use `dump` or `rsync` to recreate the filesystem from backup.
6. Reboot.

This is an invasive process and *requires* backup! If you've no backups (check that they are good!) then you *will* lose data!

Comment: I think I will recreate the VG and reformat all system. Is a good thing to not partition all the space for using it in the future for all the LV?

Comment: The best partitioning scheme is an on-going debate; because of the size of disks today some recommend a single partition for everything. Me, I recommend partitioning: `/var` `/tmp` `/home` and `/` at least - and perhaps `/usr`. If you're running a database, putting the database on its own partion is probably good too. With partitions you can use different options for each partition if you like.